# Making git probe for user before making a commit

Tags: git

We are a developer team that need to work on large machines in the lab. These machines are controlled by PC's where development also takes place. The lab PC's are always run under the same user id. The problem is that we would like git commit messages be associated by the developer user id. One method would be to request each user that comes to a machine manually runs a script that does:

```
git config user.name Foo baz
```

but the problem is that this is easily forgotten.

Instead I got the idea that perhaps I can use the `git pre-commit` hook to probe the user for her id and then run the above command. But unfortunately it doesn't work as it seems like the user.name field has already been queried before the pre-commit hook is invoked.

Another ugly idea would be to use the post-commit hook to get the user id, and then to rewrite the last commit message according to the name entered by the user. Would this work?

Does someone have any solution to this problem?

Comment: Can we assume that a session (login) is tied to a specific user? Or are the machines just left on/open?

Comment: I think the bigger question here is why the users can't just have accounts to log into. This workflow is highly abnormal... Any solution at git's end of it will just be pig lipstick.

Comment: The PC's are indeed left open in an unsecured environment under Windows, and are always running under the same user ID. The problem is that the machine must never be left without PC control for more than a short period of time, as that would be destructive. Requiring each developer to log out and log in would be an additional step that I would like to avoid. Currently subversion is used which has the advantage that the user must authenticate when doing commit. This is what I'm trying to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

You could store different users' config files in different locations, then write a script to run on login that sets `$GIT_CONFIG` to point at the user's configuration file.  Look at the `ENVIRONMENT` section of `git help config`.

Edit: If the user uses the same shell as someone else, you could write a wrapper around `git` that prompts the user, sets the environment variable, then runs the real `git`.

Comment: Unfortunately this misses the point that system is always logged in  for the same user id, so there is no login to hook onto.

Comment: I'd assumed that the user would SSH in, or in some fashion start a new session for themselves, rather than just walk up to an unsecured terminal.

Comment: Regarding the wrapper idea, it is not that simple as I have to assume that the user will not access git directly on the command line, but through tools like GitExtensions or TortoiseGit on Windows. But if these also call the command line git, then perhaps it would be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was create the global config user.name to be:

```
git config user.name CONFIGUREMEINTHELOCALREPOxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Which, at least for my version of git (1.7.5.3), is a 968 byte long value which can be set but which never will be allowed to commit. `fatal: Impossibly long personal identifier`

You can then ask the user to set the environmental variables(1) and/or local git config variables to a sane value which will allow a commit.

Yes, this too assumes the user will create a new session (environmental variables) or have a private repo (local config).  If people are sharing the same session (walking up to an unsecured pre-logged in console) I think you are probably mostly out of luck, though you can try to have $PROMPT_COMMAND check for idle-time and unset the variables or something like that, or use $TMOUT to autologout.

(1) Environmental variables in question:

```
       $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
       $GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
       $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
       $GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work as the work is done under Windows, so I can't use the $PROMPT_COMMAND or the $TMOUT approach. But thinking about it, the same effect may be achieved by having the post-commit hook erase the local GIT variables, and thus forcing to reinstall these through a script before the next commit.

Comment: @dov: Well, it depends what shell you are using.  If you are using msysgit from the git shell, you still have PROMPT_COMMAND/TMOUT.  BTW, post-commit cannot affect shell environmental variables, but of course it can delete the git config variables.